# Mitre effect while two individual paths join in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, jquery-svg

I am working with individual SVG paths and when there is a path join , need a mitre effect.Its quite new for me.

SVG shape looks like polygon , with each side as individual path.

Sample of my SVG code , does not display the original Polygon. Please see image for o/p:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 330 330">
<g id="v-3" class="joint-viewport">
  <g model-id="db69ee92-054d-4ce5-9300-ae09f385d9f2" id="j_1" class="joint-cell joint-type-custom joint-type-custom-line joint-element joint-theme-default" data-type="custom.Line" transform="translate(90,90)">
    <g class="rotatable" id="v-12">
      <g class="scalable" transform="scale(2.5,3.75)">
        <path class="path0" id="v-13" d="M 0 0 L 30 0" stroke="#806476" stroke-width="15" cursor="pointer" event="element:path-click" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
        <path class="path1" id="v-14" d="M 30 0 L 30 20" stroke="#181972" stroke-width="15" cursor="pointer" event="element:path-click" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
        <path class="path2" id="v-15" d="M 30 20 L 60 20" stroke="#91a19b" stroke-width="15" cursor="pointer" event="element:path-click" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
        <path class="path3" id="v-16" d="M 60 20 L 60 40" stroke="#f24167" stroke-width="15" cursor="pointer" event="element:path-click" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
        <path class="path4" id="v-17" d="M 60 40 L 0 40" stroke="#21e578" stroke-width="15" cursor="pointer" event="element:path-click" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
        <path class="path5" id="v-18" d="M 0 40 L 0 0" stroke="#cf2fe0" stroke-width="15" cursor="pointer" event="element:path-click" stroke-linecap="square"></path>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

The below image link of SVG shows the polygon shape. When I click on individual paths , the intersection should change as first path over the second , second path over the first and then the mitre effect. I achieved the other two , but not the mitre effect.

[SVG shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU2x9.png) 
The second image link shows the transition for each mouse click.I need to know the mitre/diagonal  effect as shown in last figure.

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc358.png)
If its the single svg , then mitre effect can be done with line-join.
How to have the mitre effect here ?

Comment: Use fill rather than stroke and draw a filled shape that has the mitre.

Comment: I need the strokeWidth to be 15.I have tried as you suggested but nothing worked. Can you please be more clear. @RobertLongson

Comment: <path class="path0" id="v-13" d="M 0 0 L 30 0" stroke="#63384e" fill="black" stroke-width="15" cursor="pointer"
          event="element:path-click" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="mitre"></path>

Comment: You don't need the stroke-width to be 15. Draw the mitred shape outline directly and fill it using the fill property.

Comment: Can you show sample please of what you mean. I need the edge to be thick enough to look. So 15 as stroke width. Can you please have a look on the images provided as links above.

Comment: Download inkscape or some other SVG editor and draw the shapes you want. Do not use stroke to draw it.

Comment: I have been given point list. I converted those point list to d paths as I need to handle them as individual paths and not as a single polygon. I can't draw the shapes as I will not be aware what that point list generates, It can be any shape. @RobertLongson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the miter you need to use shapes instead of strokes. You can do it by hand if you think that the miter is an isosceles right triangle whose catheti = 15.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 300 300" width="200">

<path id="_1"  d="M50,50L150,50 135,65 65,65z" fill="#806476"/>  
<path id="_2"  d="M150,50L150,150 135,165 135,65z" fill="#181972"/>  
<path id="_3"  d="M150,150 L250,150 235,165 135,165z" fill="#91a19b" />
<path id="_4"  d="M250,150L250,250 235 235 235 165z" fill="#f24167"/>
<path id="_5"  d="M250,250L50,250 65,235 235 235z" fill="#21e578"/>
<path id="_6"  d="M50,250L50,50 65,65 65,235z" fill="#cf2fe0" />
  
</svg>
```

Comment: The problem is I have to generate a polygon from given point list and the rendered polygon should have edges where I can manipulate its properties such as fill color, stroke width.Style shouldn't be applied for whole element but need to be applied for each edge independently.

 When I click on individual paths , the intersection should change as first path over the second , second path over the first and then the mitre effect. I achieved the other two , but not the miter effect.

Comment: This is a whole new question. Please ask a new question including a list of points: probably a javascript object. I'll be glad to help. Meanwhile please consider accepting my answer at this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52688682/edge-control-with-mitre-effect-from-given-point-list.